# Using a Default Value on Null Entry in Sybase

Tags: database-design, powerbuilder, ddl, sap-ase

Good morning,

I have a question regarding default values and NULL values in Sybase ASE 12.  To make a long story short: I have inherited a very old Sybase database as well as the PowerBuilder front end that sits on top of it.  One of the tables in question contains several columns that have default values as well as the not null constraint.  Thus, whenever no value (note: not a NULL value) is supplied, PowerBuilder creates the appropriate insert / update statement and simply does not pass a value for these empty fields, which are then automatically assigned the default value by the database.  Gravy.

Now, the problem: It was decided to add auditing to the entire application via the front end (a bad idea, I know, but not my choice).  A function was written to abstract the process of auditing but the problem arises from the fact that it sees no user entry as a NULL values and generates an insert statement into the audit table (also defined with the not null constraint), supplying the literal NULL for these empty columns.  Sybase then sees the literal NULL and, as you all know, treats the NULL as a value and not 'no entry'.

So the question: is it possible to default a NULL entry to a default values from the database side?  I have considered triggers, but I am hoping I will get lucky and there will be some form of table-level construct that I can make use of.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

**References:**
A good example of the issue in question
http://www.sybaseteam.com/null-not-nothing-difference-between-null-nothing-sybase-t-390.html

See table 7-1, halfway down the page.
http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@ebt-link;pt=20741?target=%25N%15_19279_START_RESTART_N%25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make your auditing function smarter. It should only log the columns the user changed. This is easy to determine with `getitemstatus`. You can loop through the columns using the form of `getitemstatus` that takes an integer column number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am actually doing this right now to prevent auditing rows that haven't changed, but it would be possible to and column-level granularity to it.  Ideally I was hoping to keep the the auditing function as small as possible, however, as it is already quite hefty and can take quite some time.  But, perhaps, that is indeed the way to go.  Thanks again.

Comment: Checking the properties of columns is very fast. Our framework has code that modifies every column control in a DataWindow every time it is loaded and it doesn't cause a performance hit. You'll probably come out ahead on performance by sending less data to the database. Sending the unchanged columns to the database almost surely takes longer than scanning all the columns in the DataWindow.

Comment: Hm, good to know.  I figured the database would be better optimized for such things but I imagine scanning a column value involved little more than checking a few flags.

Comment: I was thinking of the transport time for the data.